# How to allow printing from my website but disallow save as pdf?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to forbid users to save my website's content as pdf but I still want to allow them to print the content.

```
  <style media="print" type="text/css">* { display: none; }
```

The above css style hides all content so when user hits (ctrl+p) it doesn't display my content which is good.
But is there a way to only display my content when user tries printing and then if user tries to save as pdf display nothing?

Thank you,

Comment: No, and there really shouldn't be, once they can access it over the internet, they can do whatever they want with it (ie, turn on the reader view, copy pasting the text, taking screenshots, modifying your css styles to overwrite the ones you have there), so, don't even bother trying. Instead, work on some real problems :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Most operating systems implement "save as PDF" as part of the print workflow -- there's no distinction from the perspective of a web page.

As an aside, your CSS isn't going to be an effective way of preventing users from printing your content either -- if normal printing doesn't work, they'll find a workaround like taking a screenshot of the page, or copying its text into a text file.

Comment: Does the question warrant an answer though? Isn't a comment enough?

Comment: @Icepickle No, it isn't "enough". "You can't" is an answer, and comments should not be used to answer questions.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that I'm using Drupal 7 and I already have copy prevention in place so users can't copy text and it's okay if they can take screenshots and stuff but that's just an awful long process, I'd like to make it as hard for them as possible, So there's no way to only display the content when choosing to print? and hide it when users pick save to pdf?